# How to deal with missing dates in Power BI line charts? (Tabular SSAS)

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, ssas-tabular, scd2

In SSAS Tabular mode, we have different tables with slowly changing dimensions (SCD Type 2). In Power BI, we now want to show for example the price history for one object over time. I want to display that with a Line Chart.

For the sample data, I added a Line Chart and activated the "Stepped" property in "Shapes", to have a clear cut of the price change. But unfortunately, Power BI displays the price change on Oct 5th (because this is the middle date between 3th and 7th) instead of Oct 7th. I know, that I would be able to solve it on database view layer, but I don't want to create so much data records for all different tables.

```
PRICE TABLE
**************************************
Price       Valid from      Valid To
**************************************
3'674       02.10.2019      02.10.2019
3'674       03.10.2019      06.10.2019
11'095      07.10.2019      07.10.2019
11'095      08.10.2019      01.01.2999
**************************************
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior in the Power BI visualization or can I somehow calculate the missing dates in DAX?

Answer (score 0):

I would have use date field from date dimension which has all the continuous date, then you may change your axis type for date continuous and it will generate smooth transition.

[image]